# Read different line from text file to write into drawLine(line1a, line1b, line2a,line2b)

Tags: android, for-loop, ondraw

My text file contain:

```
1.232 3.456
2.341 23.41
....
```

I want to use these coordinates to draw line that continue from previous coordinate in Android eclipse.

So far my code below can read the first line(line1a & line1b) to be written into
canvas.drawLine();

```
while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] parts = line.split(" ");
  float line1a = Float.parseFloat(parts[0]);
  float line1b = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);

  // TODO
  canvas.drawLine(line1a, line1b ,line2a, line2b,  paint);
  canvas.drawLine(line2a, line2b ,line3a, line3b,  paint);
}
```

I dont know how to call line 2a,2b,3a,3b, in the same loop to create continuous line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Init point list. Here we use Float2 to represent a Point, use any
// data structure you like.
List<Float2> points = new ArrayList<Float2>();
// Create a point list from the file
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    float x = Float.parseFloat(parts[0]);
    float y = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
    points.add(new Float2(x, y));
}

// Connects these points use straight lines.
for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
    Float2 p1 = points.get(i);
    Float2 p2 = points.get(i + 1);
    canvas.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways of doing it spring to mind:
 1. Either doing first a while-loop reading all the points into an ordered dynamically allocated data structure (e.g. list or dynamic array...) called lines (containing points - pairs of floats). Then, a second loop loops over this data structure and draws lines from the first point to the second, second to third and so on. 
 2. In the existing while-loop, store the previous points in a variable with scope larger than the while loop. Then you can reuse them. Care has to be taken for the first iteration where you cannot draw yet, but only store the point.

If you want to connect the last point to the first, method 1 might be preferable (2 can be adapted by saving the first point explicitly and connecting the first and last after the while-loop ends).